How to implement a non-preemptive splitting insert in a B-tree?
I am working on implementing a non-preemptive splitting insert function for a B-tree. Below is the structure of my B-tree node:
#define KEYS_NUMBER     4                   // Max number of keys in a node
#define MIN_KEYS        (KEYS_NUMBER / 2)   // Min number of keys in a node
#define CHILDREN_NUMBER (KEYS_NUMBER + 1)   // Max number of children in a node

typedef struct node {
    bool leaf;
    int n;
    int keys[KEYS_NUMBER];
    struct node *children[CHILDREN_NUMBER];
} Node;

I have the following code for my insertNonFull and insertKey functions:
void insertNonFull(Node *node, int key) {
    int i = node->n - 1;

    if (node->leaf) {
        while (i >= 0 && (key < node->keys[i])) {
            node->keys[i + 1] = node->keys[i];
            i--;
        }
        node->keys[i + 1] = key;
        node->n = node->n + 1;
    } else {
        while (i >= 0 && key < node->keys[i]) {
            i--;
        }
        i++;
        if (node->children[i]->n == KEYS_NUMBER) {
            splitChild(node, i, node->children[i]);
            if (key > node->keys[i]) {
                i++;
            }
        }
        insertNonFull(node->children[i], key);
    }
}

void insertKey(Node **tree, int key) {
    Node *r = *tree;

    if (r->n == KEYS_NUMBER) {
        Node *s = createNode();
        *tree = s;
        s->leaf = false;
        s->n = 0;
        s->children[0] = r;
        splitChild(s, 0, r);
        insertNonFull(s, key);
    } else {
        insertNonFull(r, key);
    }
}

When I add the key 15, the B-tree structure before and after the insertion is as follows:
Before inserting the 15th key:
[3, 6, 9, 12]
    [1, 2]
    [4, 5]
    [7, 8]
    [10, 11]
    [13, 14]

After inserting the 15th key:
[9]
    [3, 6]
        [1, 2]
        [4, 5]
        [7, 8]
    [12]
        [10, 11]
        [13, 14, 15]

We can see that the root node splits prematurely. How can I optimize my insert function to prevent this premature split and achieve the following result instead?
[3, 6, 9, 12]
    [1, 2]
    [4, 5]
    [7, 8]
    [10, 11]
    [13, 14, 15]

Any suggestions on how to adjust my insertNonFull and insertKey functions to achieve this?

How can you tell if a node doesn't need to be split (before splitting it)?

@ScottHunter I need to check if these children are full first ?

What happened when you tried that?

@ScottHunterIf the child is full, I split it, but I split the root or the node before splitting the child. I want to split it in this order: child -> parent -> ... -> parent -> root. How can I do that?

What did you try, and how did it go wrong?

@ScottHunter I tried to create a large recursive insertion function, but it was always prematurely splitting my root or my full parent nodes before splitting the child. I believe I have a logical issue in my thinking process.

You need to recurse into the tree till you are at a child. Then you insert the new item and potentially split the child. You return either nothing or the new key + child to insert in the parent. In the parent you insert the new key + child, potentially splitting the parent too. So as you return from the recursion you do the splitting as needed.


Insertion is done at leaf node. If this operation causes the node to be overfull, the node is split into two, with the median element promoted. This cascades up the tree.

As I see it, the literature is very fuzzy on the implementation details, specifically, how does it become "overfull" and how do you do this "promotion". After seeing a lot of B-tree implementations, I can think of 3 approaches.

Pre-emptively and greedily split any full nodes on the way down the tree, whether needed it or not. This is a very popular approach because of its simplicity. However, as you have noticed, results in a tree that is non-optimal and slightly unbalanced, (although it becomes less noticeable for high B.)
Do the steps literally. Either add a parent pointer (double-linking) and an extra temporary overfull entry to every node to help with the transition (update the pointers every time there is a change in topology) or use temporary space (ie an O(log n) stack of pointers to nodes).
We know, almost independently, how each of the nodes split on the inserted key, with the exception of 1 hole that gets filled from the child. This means that we can skip directly to the final topology and do the allocation of new nodes and promotion in any order we like; specifically, down the tree instead of up. This also is advantageous because one moves the memory only once. (However, it is a lot of cases.)

Choosing this last approach, on descent from the root to the leaf, we need to keep track of the lowest height node that is not-full. If the path is entirely full of keys, one requires an increase of height. Then you know exactly how many, O(log n), extra nodes you need to complete the insertion.
For example, adding 9 into full 3-tree, where there is no lowest not-full, requires 4 extra nodes to increase the height. The lowest not-full becomes the new root.

Backtrack to the lowest not-full and re-descend, splitting the data and the hole between existing, full child (child 1) node, one entry from the lowest not-full (parent) node, and the newly-allocated (child 2) node. The hole node should have the new key's value, which it will be eventually replaced.

Now the lowest not-full is the child of the previous along the path to the new key. Repeat.

The hole skipped ahead to exactly where insertion should be if we followed all the steps in the bottom-up B-tree algorithm.

The result is as if one had promoted upwards, but we just skipped the intermediate steps. The animations on this visualization from David Galles helped me a lot with my implementation.

Thank you for your detailed response and for introducing me to the site with David Galles' animations. However, I need to maintain my current data structure without changes. My objective is to adjust my insert function to avoid preemptive splitting. Any suggestions on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again for your help!

The animations are cool, right? Oops, I changed it to be clear what algorithm variation I was talking about; only 2. where you do exactly what it says in the algorithm do you need, possibly, to modify your data structure. If your next goal is to not pre-emptively split, then I would try with O(log n) extra space (stack) because it's a fairly easy to translate the algorithm to C with this scratch space.
